# Why AsQueryable is so slow with Linq?

Tags: performance, linq

I faced a rather stupid performance issue in my code. After a small investigation, i have found that AsQueryable method i used to cast my generic list slows down the code up to 8000 times.
So the the question is, why is that?
Here is the example

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new ContainerTest();
        c.FillList();

        var s = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            c.TestLinq(true);
        }
        var e = Environment.TickCount;
        Console.WriteLine("TestLinq AsQueryable - {0}", e - s);

        s = Environment.TickCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            c.TestLinq(false);
        }
        e = Environment.TickCount;
        Console.WriteLine("TestLinq as List - {0}", e - s);

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to finish");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class ContainerTest
{
    private readonly List<int> _list = new List<int>();
    private IQueryable<int> _q; 

    public void FillList()
    {
        _list.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            _list.Add(i);
        }
        _q = _list.AsQueryable();
    }

    public Tuple<int, int> TestLinq(bool useAsQ)
    {
        var upperBorder = useAsQ ? _q.FirstOrDefault(i => i > 7) : _list.FirstOrDefault(i => i > 7);
        var lowerBorder = useAsQ ? _q.TakeWhile(i => i < 7).LastOrDefault() : _list.TakeWhile(i => i < 7).LastOrDefault();            

        return new Tuple<int, int>(upperBorder, lowerBorder);
    }
}
```

UPD As i understand, i have to avoid AsQueryable method as much as possible(if it's not in the line of inheritance of the container), because i'll get *immediately* performance issue

"and avoid the moor in those hours of darkness when the powers of evil are exalted"

Comment: you know that both test doesn't give the same result

Comment: Ugh, thanks. You've found a bug:)

Comment: Why are you calling AsQueryable on this collection? That is not appropriate at all for this use. It's causing your LINQ methods afterward to expect to be building a different kind of expression tree, not meant for simply collections, but for "queryable" things... like a database table.

Comment: Because initially i wanted to use it with BindingList<T>, and i found my performance issue. But for LIst<T> it shouldn't affect performance, since List<T> _is_ IQueryable, so even if i call AsQueryable() it has to return list as IQueryable directly -> linq has to be executed as expression tree -> fast. But it's not

Comment: Oh. List is not IQueryable, my bad.

Comment: Exactly; `List` is not `IQueryable`. The implementations of the standard query operators are very different between the two. If you don't need `IQueryable`, then don't call `AsQueryable`. It's a different beast entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same issue.

The thing is that `IQueryable<T>` takes `Expression<Func<T, Bool>>` as parameter for  filtering in `Where()`/`FirstOrDefault()` calls - as opposed of just the `Func<T, Bool>` pre-compiled delegate taken in simple `IEnumerable`'s correspondent methods.

That means there will be a compile phase to transform the `Expression` into a `delegate`. And this costs quite a lot.

Now you need that in a loop (just I did)? You'll get in some trouble...

---

PS: It seems .NET Core/.NET 5 [improves this significantly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62679981/666104). Unfortunately, our projects are not there yet...

Answer (score 0):

at least use LINQ with List too

manual implementation will always be faster than LINQ

**EDIT**

you know that both test doesn't give the same result

Comment: Performance difference using LINQ over foreach is marginal.  It is nowhere *near* an 8000 times difference.  (frankly it's nowhere near a 2 times difference)

Comment: @kirk woll, both test doesn't give result and don't use same implementation

Comment: Ok, try TestLinq method only, one time with just List<T>, second time with List<T>.AsQuerable

Answer (score 0):

Because `AsQueryable` returns an `IQueryable`, which has a completely different set of extension methods for the LINQ standard query operators from the one intended for things like `List`.

`Queryable` collections are meant to have a backing store of an RDBMS or something similar, and you are building a different, more complex code expression tree when you call `IQueryable.FirstOrDefault()` as opposed to `List<>.FirstOrDefault()`.